# Replacing geometry of a polygon using the geometry of a polygon from another layer

Tags: editing, arcgis-pro

I am trying to update a polygon shapefile by redoing the geometry on certain polygons to match the geometry of polygons in a separate, more accurate shapefile. Some of these polygons are extremely complex, and the replace geometry tool is taking much too long.

Is there a tool or method that would allow me to alter a polygon to match exactly the geometry of a polygon in a separate layer while retaining the attributes of the original polygon?

I vaguely recall doing this in ArcMap, but ArcGIS Pro is throwing me for a loop.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to stay in Pro as opposed to just doing it in Map? Pro doesn't have nearly the toolset that Map does yet. It doesn't look like [Pro's tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/editing/basics/replace-the-geometry-of-a-feature.htm) will let you select or paste a geometry as part of the process, and I'm not seeing comparable tools to the Map version work-arounds. Not having used Pro, is there a way you can just paste the shape as a new feature and copy the attributes, then delete the original?

Answer (score 2):

Select the polygon and copy it (either via the clipboard, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> , or right click and copy) and **Paste Special**. You will then have the option to what layer you paste it to (like in ArcMap) and can also select if you want to copy attributes or not.